# How do I skip a before method in a specific test?

Tags: java, selenium, annotations, testng

I have a POM framework. In the BaseTest class I have the following @BeforeMethod

```
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
@Parameters("url")
public void goHome(String URL) {
    driver.get(URL);
    this.setInventoryPage(
            new LoginPage(driver)
                    .setUsername(this.getSauceUserName())
                    .setPassword(this.getSaucePassword())
                    .clickLoginButton());
}
```

That method includes the login steps so I don't have to add the same line of code in all the tests. Now, the issue is that I have the following 2 test scenarios in the LoginTests class (locked account and wrong credentials). My LoginTests class extends BaseTests class.

```
@Test(groups = {"Login", "Negative" })
public void lockedCredentials(){
    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    loginPage.setUsername("wrong_user");
    loginPage.setPassword("secret_sauce");
    loginPage.clickLoginButton();
    assertTrue(loginPage.getErrorMessageText()
                    .contains("Epic sadface: Sorry, this user has been locked out."),
            "Credentials are not locked!");
}

@Test(groups = {"Login", "Negative"})
public void invalidCredentials(){
    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    loginPage.setUsername("wrong_user");
    loginPage.setPassword("wrong_pass");
    loginPage.clickLoginButton();
    assertTrue(loginPage.getErrorMessageText()
                    .contains("Epic sadface: Username and password do not match any user in this service"),
            "The credentials entered are valid!");
}
```

My question is how do I ignore the above @BeforeMethod for the above 2 tests scenarios (just for locked account and wrong credentials)?

Note: I'm using TestNG.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to skip `@BeforeMethod`.

A workaround here could be moving those two methods to the subclass of your Test and overriding the `goHome` method.

Example:

```java
public abstract class LoginTest {
    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void goHome() {
        System.out.println("Going Home...");
    }
}

class NegativeLoginTest extends LoginTest {
    @Override
    public void goHome() {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Test(groups = {"Login", "Negative"})
    public void lockedCredentials() {
        System.out.println("Locked Credentials");
    }

    @Test(groups = {"Login", "Negative"})
    public void invalidCredentials() {
        System.out.println("Invalid Credentials");
    }
}


class PositiveLoginTest extends LoginTest {
    @Test(groups = {"Login", "Positive" })
    public void correctCredentials(){
        System.out.println("Correct Credentials");
    }
}
```

There are three classes in the example:

- LoginTest - base class for Login tests
- PositiveLoginTest - all the tests call `LoginTest#goHome` before each method
- NegativeLoginTest - owerrides `goHome` method, so `LoginTest#goHome` won't be called

Comment: Do you mean an inner class? I created an inner class but I could not figure out how to add that class in my testNG file so the tests in that inner class can be executed. Is it possible that you can provide an example of your workaround?

Comment: I've added the example to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

In TestNG, you can exclude specific @BeforeMethod annotations from running for a particular @Test method by using the @Test's dependsOnMethods attribute. Here's an example:

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClass {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        // This method will run before every test method
        System.out.println("Setup");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        // Test 1 code here
        System.out.println("Test 1");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "test1")
    public void test2() {
        // This method depends on test1, so @BeforeMethod won't run for this method
        System.out.println("Test 2");
    }
}
```

In the example above, the setup() method is annotated with @BeforeMethod, which means it will run before every test method. However, the test2() method has dependsOnMethods = "test1" attribute in its @Test annotation, indicating that it depends on test1. This means that test2() will only run if test1() passes, and the setup() method won't be executed before test2().

By specifying the dependencies in this way, you can exclude the @BeforeMethod annotation from running for specific @Test methods in TestNG.

Comment: This looks like it was ChatGPT generated

Comment: Nope it was generated by me